# "Inverse" homomorphism of a group monomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $\varphi:H\rightarrow G$ is a finite group monomorphism. Is it true that there exists a homomorphism
$$
\psi:G\rightarrow H
$$
such that
$$
\psi\circ\varphi=id_H?
$$

Comment: $\varphi \colon \mathbb{Z}/(2) \to \mathbb{Z}/(4)$ given by $x + 2\mathbb{Z} \mapsto 2x + 4\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not in general.

Consider $G$ any [simple group of non-prime order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) $n$ and let $p|n$ be a prime. Then $G$ has $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a proper subgroup ([Cauchy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory))). Thus we have a monomorphism (the inclusion)

$$f:\mathbb{Z}_p\to G$$

This monomorphism does not have the one-sided inverse, because there's only one homomorphism $g:G\to\mathbb{Z}_p$, namely the trivial one.

Indeed, if $g$ is non-trivial, then $\ker(g)$ is a proper normal subgroup of $G$. Since $G$ is simple then $\ker(g)$ has to be trivial and thus $g$ has to be a monomorphism. This is impossible since $p < n$.